# Какой порядок действий в git актуализации данных сервера?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Есть два сайта одинаковых (битрикс проект), но чуть-чуть отличающихся по содержанию. Один адрес, допустим, условно https://site1.ru боевой сервер и дев-сервер https://site1.dev.studio.ru. У меня есть данные доступа боевого сервера SSH/SFTP: ssh root@191.200.50.31 пароль: xFPy11F1 и данные доступа дев-сервера: 150.250.15.168, ssh auto@150.250.15.168 логин: auto пароль: Dljzz455fjR8679e. Есть репозиторий также на гитлабе, с данными с боевого сервера.

1. Как мне перенести данные с помощью git (пушнуть) с боевого сервера на дев-сервер и тем самым синхронизировать контент сайтов?
2. Вопрос второй. Мне нужно выполнять команды git в локальной командой строке (windows cms) или нужна специальная программа для передачи команд (ssh-клиент)?
3. Мне нужно копировать на локальный компьютер копию боевого сервера для переноса данных или можно просто напрямую, через репозиторий синхронизировать данные?
4. Как потом добавлять изменения и сохранять данные в файлах на серверах боевом и дев? Php-Storm подойдет для таких целей, как удаленное изменение файлов на серверах? Какой-то терминал использовать для ввода git-команд?

Расскажите все на пальцах, чтобы я понял, как действовать. Спасибо за ответы. Гит знаю в общих чертах, но такие вопросы никогда не решал.

Comment: Это очень плохая идея публиковать в общий доступ адрес, логин и пароль

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, эти данные условные, не реальные. Просто нужно, чтобы кто-то объяснил все как есть по гиту.

Comment: git это система контролей версий, а вам нужна миграция данных

Comment: @user7860670, разве тут гитом нельзя это сделать? то есть у меня два сайта (боевой и тестовый -dev). На обоих одинаковый сайт, но на боевом сайте были сделаны свежие правки и коммиты. Нужно слить  изменения из ветки боевого сервера на дев-сервер, сделать слияние кода. Мне задачу ставят говорят гит надо использовать. Не думаю, что здесь миграция данных.

Comment: Ну если это сайт со статическим содержимым (т.е. без бд или вообще пользовательских данных), то можно и через гит. Но просто перенести файлы можно и просто посредством ftp

Comment: @user7860670, мне не нужно просто ftp. Сайт не статика, а битрикс проект с бд. БД уже стоит одинаковая на двух серверах. Мне нужно слить из боевого сервера все изменения на репозиторий гитлаба, а оттуда передать данные на дев-сервер. Как удаленно на сервере можно выполнить команды гита или надо через терминал ssh-клиент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно люди просто копируют файлы с сервера на сервер с помощью какого-нибудь WinSCP, но если вам хочется добавить немного извращений в свою жизнь, то почему бы и не использовать гит?

Чтобы перенести код с боевого на дев:

1. коннектитесь на боевой сервер (ssh или что там у вас для этого стоит)
2. в командной строке боевого сервера выполняете
   `cd git_repo && git add . && git commit -m'bla-bla' && git push`
3. на дев сервере выполняете `git pull`

Ну, и чтобы всё это работало, нужно предварительно создать пустой репозиторий на gitlab, и на обоих серверах (боевом и дев) выполнить `git clone https://путь_к_гитлаб_репо`, оно создаcт папку и инициализирует локальную репу, которую уже после это нужно наполнить вашими файлами

В принципе, какая-то польза от гита тут есть: он экономит трафик при копировании репы (т.е., пересылает только разницу содержимого файлов, а WinSCP перешлёт весь файл)
Но думаю, размер исходников сайта у вас сравнительно мал, и экономить трафик необходимости нет

Comment: Не сказал бы, что размер исходников сайта мал. Весь проект весит около 1ГБ вместе с картинками, стилями, скриптами и ядром битрикса. Это я понял, спасибо за ответ. Но остались вопросы. Как я могу обратиться к командой строке боевого сервера и дев сервера? Программа нужна какая-то, чтобы вбивать команды гит и наличие на сервере гита, наверное.

Comment: Я запускаю WinSCP (это программа для копирования файлов), там нажимаю Ctrl+P, открывается PuTTY (окно терминала), туда вбиваю юниксовые команды.  Но можно и без всего этого, просто открыть cmd.exe, в нём запустить ssh.exe (не помню, ставил я ssh отдельно или он уже был в винде)